# How to convert this to use composition api script setup in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I use the composition api with script setup for my project and I was needing this part of the vue-select npm package. But I am not entirely sure how to convert it.

```
<template>
  <v-select
    :options="paginated"
    :filterable="false"
    @open="onOpen"
    @close="onClose"
    @search="(query) => (search = query)"
  >
    <template #list-footer>
      <li v-show="hasNextPage" ref="load" class="loader">
        Loading more options...
      </li>
    </template>
  </v-select>
</template>

<script>
import countries from '../data/countries'

export default {
  name: 'InfiniteScroll',
  data: () => ({
    observer: null,
    limit: 10,
    search: '',
  }),
  computed: {
    filtered() {
      return countries.filter((country) => country.includes(this.search))
    },
    paginated() {
      return this.filtered.slice(0, this.limit)
    },
    hasNextPage() {
      return this.paginated.length < this.filtered.length
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    /**
     * You could do this directly in data(), but since these docs
     * are server side rendered, IntersectionObserver doesn't exist
     * in that environment, so we need to do it in mounted() instead.
     */
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(this.infiniteScroll)
  },
  methods: {
    async onOpen() {
      if (this.hasNextPage) {
        await this.$nextTick()
        this.observer.observe(this.$refs.load)
      }
    },
    onClose() {
      this.observer.disconnect()
    },
    async infiniteScroll([{ isIntersecting, target }]) {
      if (isIntersecting) {
        const ul = target.offsetParent
        const scrollTop = target.offsetParent.scrollTop
        this.limit += 10
        await this.$nextTick()
        ul.scrollTop = scrollTop
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.loader {
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbbbbb;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What did you try? "not entirely" presumes that you can convert it some extent, so this doesn't require other users to write the whole component for you.

Comment: The part I really do not know about is the mounted(), async, and IntersectionObserver stuff.

Comment: Lifecycle hooks are described in the docs, it's onMounted. Async doesn't really affect anything here, it's just a function that uses promises. It's unknown what's your case with SSR but don't evaluate any browser-specific code on server side. mounted hook isn't supposed to be triggered, so that's where IntersectionObserver belongs

Comment: You can update question with were you are stuck with the code to get better answers

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to reqrite that code without knowing what you tried and what external variables/scripts are available.
Maybe this gives you an idea how this could look in setup script:

```
<template>
<v-select
    :options="paginated"
    :filterable="false"
    @open="onOpen"
    @close="onClose"
    @search="(query) => (search = query)"
>
    <template #list-footer>
        <li v-show="hasNextPage" ref="load" class="loader">Loading more 

options...</li>
        </template>
    </v-select>
</template>

<script setup>
import countries from "../data/countries";
import { onMounted, computed, ref } from "vue";

const observer = ref(null);
const limit = ref(10);
const search = "";

const filtered = computed(() => {
    return countries.filter((country) => country.includes(this.search));
});

const paginated = computed(() => {
    return filtered.value.slice(0, this.limit);
});

const hasNextPage = computed(() => {
    return paginated.value.length < this.filtered.length;
});

onMounted(() => {
    observer.value = new IntersectionObserver(infiniteScroll);
});

async function onOpen() {
    if (hasNextPage) {
        await $nextTick();
        observer.value.observe($refs.load);
    }
}

function onClose() {
    observer.value.disconnect();
}

async function infiniteScroll([{ isIntersecting, target }]) {
    if (isIntersecting) {
        const ul = target.offsetParent;
        const scrollTop = target.offsetParent.scrollTop;
        limit.value += 10;
        await $nextTick();
        ul.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.loader {
    text-align: center;
    color: #bbbbbb;
}
</style>
```